# Is it okay to say یا رسول الله

Tags: practical-islam

It is okay to say **یا رسول الله**.

The word **"یا"** means **"O"** which only can be used if somebody is in front of you. If I say **"یا الله"** then it is okay because Allah is everywhere so I can say this but should I say **"یا رسول الله"** because our Prophet Muhammad (SAW) is not in front of us.

I am asking this question because their are two mosques in my area and in both mosques "یا رسول الله" is written along with "یا الله" so one of my cousin refuse to offer pray in these mosques because he *"my cousin"* said "my prayer won't be accepted if I offer my prayer in these mosques".

Comment: Prophet's soul is still in existence and He hears us and sees us. So we can use Prophet as means  of seeking nearness to Allah. This is called [Tawasoul](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16772/umar-ra-recoursed-tawassol-to-the-uncle-of-the-prophets-sunni-view/16773?noredirect=1#comment30950_16773). But your friend must be a follower of salafist or wahhabi school as these schools consider calling Prophet for help and support as tantamount to shirk!

Comment: Yes they think.

Comment: [Q&A of Tawasoul](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16772/umar-ra-recoursed-tawassol-to-the-uncle-of-the-prophets-sunni-view/16773?noredirect=1#comment30950_16773) you mentioned is completely going other direction. I want to take it generally. Let make it clear, can you provide reference from **Ayah** or **Hadith** that Tawasoul is right.

Comment: Also in that Q&A, the OP asking question and used Tawassol with recourse so tell why recourse with tawassol. Both words have different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

We beleive that prophet muhammed passed away so we cannot address him anymore. We should try and preach this in mosque such as yours.  I am not sure about praying there because your cousin has a point but i think i would pray in such a mosque if time is running out and there are no other options

Comment: Please back up your answer by citing Islamic sources. Not all schools of jurisprudence consider calling on Prophet for support haram.

Comment: I am not asking either I can pray in that mosque or not. I am asking, is it right to call **یا رسول الله**?

Comment: No, you cannot. He passed away. "Ya" is used for people who are alive. We do not believe that he is alive because in the quran it is clearly mentioned in Ayat ul qursi that only Allah Almighty can live forever. In surah rahman Ayah 26 it is mentioned again that every Makhlooq on the planet is suppose to end

Answer (score -2):

when we pass from grave yard or enter the graveyard we have to say "as-salam-o-alaikum-ya-aehlal-quboor" there is no shirk or such haram thing in that then way so in saying "ya-rasul-allah"